# Angular Unable to Init Service (HttpClient) in a Class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to isolate http interactions by creating data access objects from a class so that in a component I might simply get data like this:

```
// dashboard.component
import { AppUser } from './appuser.service'

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  user: AppUser = new AppUser();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let id = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('session')).userId;
    this.user.find(id) // 'find' is from base class
      .subscribe(
        // handle user data
      );
  }
}
```

I have defined a base class and a sub class like this:

```
// base-resource.service
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
...
export class BaseResource {
  private fullpath: string;
  protected http: HttpClient;

  constructor (path: string) {
    this.fullpath = path;
  }

  find (id): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.get(this.fullpath + '/' + id); // this line throws Error!
  }
}

// app-user.service
...
export class AppUser extends BaseResource {
  constructor(data?) {
    super('api/appusers');
  }
}
```

However this generates an error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` from within the base class function.

My 'AppUser' instance is clearly inheriting `find` from 'BaseResource', but `find` is picking up the 'AppUser' instance as the value of `this` and `http` is not available. I have tried declaring `http` as public and private as well as protected, but that had no effect. I imagine I'm missing some bigger picture of how to extend classes.

As specifically as possible, i think my question is in how to abstract functions to a base class when they need access to the base class's context.

(using Angular 6.0.4)

EDIT
I updated the title as it became clear that this is a problem of instantiating the HttpClient service in a class.

Comment: Is it throwing a compilation eror or a runtme error? From what I can see, you never initialise `http` anywhere, so it'll be undefined.

Comment: The error is a runtime error. I'm importing `HttpClient` in BaseResource. It is not injected via the constructor, because (I think) that prevents "newing up" an instance. I certainly could be wrong on that particular point, though.

Comment: Yeah, importing it doesn't create an instance, it's just needed for type safety. Will you ever need to inject `BaseResource` directly, or will it always be a class that extends `BaseResource`?

Comment: If I still need to instantiate it, maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49507928/how-to-inject-httpclient-in-static-method-or-custom-class has my answer. It is my intent to never use BaseResource directly.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because nothing is instantiating HttpClient, so it is undefined when you come to use it.

You should inject `HttpClient` into `AppUser`, and pass it into `BaseResource` via the constructor

```
export class AppUser extends BaseResource {
  constructor(HttpClient http) {
    super(http, 'api/appusers');
  }
}
```

And in base-resource.service

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
...
export class BaseResource {
  private fullpath: string;
  protected http: HttpClient;

  constructor (httpClient: HttpClient, path: string) {
    this.fullpath = path;
    this.http = httpClient;
  }

  find (id): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.get(this.fullpath + '/' + id); // this line throws Error!
  }
}
```

Comment: I made a quick pass at passing it in and was able to access `http`; its definitely missing instantiation. However, it seems 'wrong' at some level to be passing in an 'HttpClient' instance in every call to an instance of this class. If I needed a dozen services, or if I needed to add one more service it seems I'd have to update every call which is what I wanted to avoid by abstracting in the first place.